Aggregating classes in confusion matrix for a multi-class classifier
I have a 6 class classifier. My target classes would be class 1 and 2. Can I sum the TP, FN, FP values of Class 1 and Class 2 and calculate the Precision and Recall from the aggregate values? Or would I need to go back to the classifier and create a separate Confusion matrix with class 1 and class 2 combined at the beginning?
